# problema ao converter texto para minúsculo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Galera criei uma função que converto o texto para minúsculo dentro do input, o problema e que quando informo um input com value, e tendo alterar algo o cursor pula para o final. Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Meu código:

```js
// Converte minusculas em maiusculas
function up(lstr) {
    var str = lstr.value;
    lstr.value = str.toUpperCase();
}
```

```html
<input OnKeyUp='up(this)' type='text' class='form_campos form_campos_simples' id='inputNormal' name='historico' value="TESTANDO O TEXTO">
```

Comment: tente adicionar no javascript: nome_formulario.historico.focus(); salvo que nome_formulario esteja configurado na tag form Ex: <form name="nome_formulario" acrion="">

Comment: poderia me dar um exemplo prático? não entendi muito bem isso.

Comment: Não bastaria usar CSS? `text-transform: lowercase;`?

Comment: não funcionou não, olha ai:http://jsfiddle.net/f3vpyhnk/16/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não precisa usar função, usa assim direto no input:

```
onkeyUP="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()"
```

Usando Ajax, permite edição em qualquer parte do campo sem pular o cursor:

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("#NOME_DO_SEU_INPUT").on('input', function(){

    // armazena posição corrente
    var start = this.selectionStart,
        end = this.selectionEnd;

    this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();

    // restaura posição armazenada anteriormente.
    this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="NOME_DO_SEU_INPUT" />
```

[Adaptação daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508707/updating-an-inputs-value-without-losing-cursor-position)

Comment: bom sua alternativa contem o mesmo problema da minha função, quando pego um input com value definido, não e possível alterar ele, pois o cursor pula para o final após digitar algo nele. vc tem uma solução para isso?

Comment: Veja nesse link, usando Ajax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508707/updating-an-inputs-value-without-losing-cursor-position

Comment: Veja na minha resposta, adicionei o Ajax que deve te ajudar.

Comment: desculpa minha ignorância mas ainda não consegui fazer funcionar, o problema continua, da uma olha de como esta o código: http://jsfiddle.net/f3vpyhnk/14/

Comment: apague o "UpCase" e coloque o nome do seu input, mantendo o #. Depois, apague o onkeyUP="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" que está no input.

Comment: amigo, testei aqui e editei a resposta. Copie exatamente a resposta que coloquei, apenas mude o nome do seu input.

Comment: ainda não deu certo. da uma olha ai no código como ficou:http://jsfiddle.net/f3vpyhnk/15/  Tem mais uma coisa, desta forma não funcionaria, pois tenho um form com vários input

Comment: use assim o input: <input type="Text" name="teste" id ="teste">. Quanto aos outros campos, é só adicionar o nome deles na função.

Comment: sua função funcionou perfeitamente, porém para mim ela não ira funcionar, pois os meus input eu ja uso o nome para varias outras coisas e tbm id para outras funções de montagem do formulário. preciso de uma função que eu possa chamar através do entendo onkeyUP ou chamar através se outra forma. Tem alguma forma de fazer isso com sua função?

Comment: basta adicionar as variáveis separando por virgula: #teste, #teste2, #teste3.....

Comment: eu entendi, mesmo assim fica inviável. ja sei, tem alguma forma de atribuir sua função para todos os elementos input? ou seja ela iria executar para todos os input, independente do id ou name. Isso tem como fazer?

Comment: Da forma que te mostrei executa para todos, bastando por o nome como te expliquei, separando por virgulas no inicio da função.

Comment: eu sei, mas não da para eu criar um id cara todos os input pois são muito os inout do sistema entende. Se eu fazer ele executar em todas as tag <input> seria muito mais prático e o código ficaria muito muito menor. serio o sistema tem em torno de uns 800 input, imagina o tamanha que ficaria o código. Por isso estou te perguntando se em como executar ele em todas as tag <input>

Answer (score 1):

Bom com a ajuda do diego chegou a seguinte solução:

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('input').on('input', function(){

    // Armazena posição corrente do cursor
    var start = this.selectionStart,
        end = this.selectionEnd;

    this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();

    // Restaura posição armazenada anteriormente.
    this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input nome="campo1">
<input nome="campo2">
<input nome="campo3">
<input nome="campo4">
<input nome="campo5">
<input nome="campo6">
<input nome="campo7">
```

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Que bom que ajudou. Se puder marcar minha resposta como certa, agradeço. Obrigado.